# Populate UITableView with NSDictionary contained parsed JSON data from a mysql db

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsdictionary

Very familiar with Android programming, however very new to iOS (and Objective - C).

I am calling a remote php file within my application and (I believe) successfully parsing the JSON results according to my NSLOG results.  Example:

```
2013-01-17 14:24:30.611 JSON TESTING 4[1309:1b03] Deserialized JSON Dictionary = {
products =     (
            {
        BF = "";
        EN = "2342";
        Measure = ft;
        Name = "Brian";
        "Name_id" = 1;
        Home = "New York";
        "DB_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        BF = "";
        EN = "2123";
        Measure = ft;
        Name = "Rex";
        "Name_id" = 3;
        Home = "New York";
        "DB_id" = 5;
    }
);
success = 1;
```

}

My question lies in how to populate this information into a table view.  I can customize a prototype cell, but where do I go from there?

EDIT:

Here is my code for the view setup:

```
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return productArray.count;
    NSLog(@"Number of arrays %u", productArray.count);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    NSDictionary *productDictionary = [productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"BF"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self launchTest];
}
```

and my .h file

```
@interface tpbaMasterViewController : UITableViewController 
{
    NSDictionary *lists;
    NSArray *productArray;
}

- (void) launchTest;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;



@end
```

Comment: lists = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
productArray = [lists objectForKey:@"products"];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You access the objects in a `NSDictionary` using `objectForKey` methods.  For example, to get an `NSArray` of the products in the dictionary:

```
NSArray *productArray = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"products"];
```

Now you have an array with two dictionary objects.  For the various `UITableViewDataSource` methods you can query the array.  A couple of examples:

For `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, return the number of objects in the array:

```
`return productArray.count;`
```

And for `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
NSDictionary *productDictionary = [productArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.bfLabel.text = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"BF"];
    myCell.enLabel.text = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"EN"];
   //  continue doing the same for the other product information
```

Declaring `productArray` in the .m file as shown below makes it visible within your view controller (assumes `productDictionary` is a property:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewController () {
    NSArray *productArray;
}
@end
...
@implementation MyCollectionViewController

    -(void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];

        productArray = [self.myDictionary objectForKey:@"products"];
    }
...
@end
```

Comment: With the new Objective-C syntax, you can write [myDictionary objectForKey:@"products"] as myDictionary[@"products"]

Comment: Thanks for this.  Where do I declare my NSArray *productArray to use it throughout my UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: @ADK - you can declare it in the interface block in your .m file.  Updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help,  appreciate it.  I edited my question above to show my supporting code.  My program still runs, but nothing actually populates on the TableView itself (Log is still spitting out parsed JSON properly, I didn't paste that method since I assume that is working fine).

Comment: Couple of things...I don't see where `productArray` is set, and the lines of code in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` need to be reversed.

Comment: productArray is set in my main method (added the lines above).  Could you clarify what exactly needs to be reversed on your second point?

Comment: In the `numberOfRowsInSection` method, the `return` statement comes before the `NSLog`, so the `NSLog` will never be executed.

Comment: The issue looks like my productArray is empty during the UI building.  However I am able to NSLOG it fine in my main method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22988/discussion-between-bobnoble-and-adk)

Comment: bobnoble - you rock!  The problem was a combination of the JSON data not parsing before the UI loaded, and I was having to call a reloadData in the appropriate spot.  Thanks a lot!